# How to load route only when request is resolved (not when the user enters the path to the browser)

Tags: angularjs, redirect, authentication, routes

I have reset password in my application. If everything works fine user must see new page with information about checking inbox. 
I can do it, I just set new route:

```
    .module('auth')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('success', {
                url: '/success',
                templateUrl: 'app/authentication/success.html',
                data: {
                    hasPublicAccess: true
                }

//if I don't set hasPublicAccess to true, I'm redirect to home page 


            })

and in my reset password I have after resolved: 

                .finally(function () {
                     $state.go('success');
                });
```

And it works fine of course, but I have a doubt, because when I type this path to browser like '/success' I can see this page and It's doesn't make sense for me. 
Where I must put condition that I can open this route only when request is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

`$stateProvider.state(...)` has `resolve` property. There you can implement all checks/loads that need to be performed before state is loaded. (for example https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c)